# Xamarin Forms System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin.forms, system.net.webexception

I am creating an android app using Xamarin.Forms. 
On toggling internet connectivity off and on frequently, i am getting **System.Net.WebException ConnectFailure** exception. I have tried to handle it in my PCL code but it is not getting caught in there. 
Following is the sample code of shared project of Xamarin.Forms.

```
 public async Task GetNewSomething(CancellationToken token)
    {
          await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    await Task.Delay(10000, token);
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) // check if internet is available
                    {
                        try
                        {   
                            //Make server call to get data
                            FacilityManager.GetAllFacilities(list =>
                            {
                              //For testing purpose : Intentionally thowing an exception to check if we can catch it in the catch block below.  
                                throw new WebException();
                                MessagingCenter.Send(list, "FreshFacilityListFromServer");
                            }, 0, true);
                        }
                        catch (WebException ex)
                        {
                       //It is never gets caught here. :(
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, token);
        }
    }
```

Can someone please guide me how can i handle WebException in the given catch block. Appreciate all feedback's.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this too. I managed to catch it by using:

```
catch (System.Net.WebException ex) {}
```

For some reason, it is not bubbling for me and halting execution even when i try to re-throw it; however i'm able to force it to bubble and eventually handle it by rewrapping the exception.

```
public async Task DownloadAndInstall(...)
{
  ...

  // Download
  try
   {
      await Download(...)
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new DownloadException("Something bad happened");
   }
   ...
}

public async Task Download(...)
{
   ...
   // try some web activity
   try
   {
      ...
   }
   catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
   {
      throw new Exception("Uncaught exception", ex);
   }
   ...
}
```